# Timezone format difference post weblogic upgrade from 10.3.0 to 10.3.6.0.11

Tags: java, oracle, weblogic, weblogic-10.x, java-6

My application (Java Component) makes a procedure call and receives a SQL XML in the form of a REF CURSOR and delivers the output.
The application is deployed in JRockit 160_05 and Weblogic 10.3.0.
Post upgrade to Weblogic 10.3.6.0_11 a slight difference in the Timezone appended to all the Timestamp elements of the XML.
With the same database and same data, the difference is being noticed only after the upgrade. In the database the output is as expected
Database is oracle 10.2.4.0
current Java version: JDK 1.6.0_105
current weblogic 10.3.6.0_11
Format difference sample:
Pre Upgrade:
11/16/2015 10:14:49 +0.00

Post Upgrade:
11/16/2015 09:00:25 GB

As it is seen above, the difference is observed in the Timezone.. in output we are getting unexpectedly 'GB' instead of '+0.00'

Can someone help me on resolving this issue please?

Comment: it is clear this is a JDK issue more than WLS version issue. Have you tried changing JDK ?

Answer (score 1):

Though this looks like a jdbc driver issue, try changing the value of NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT property in your database (Not a optimal solution). Set that format to use zone offset (ex: 1999-01-15 8:00:00 **-8:00**) instead of zoneid . Hope that helps
Please refer: 
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch4datetime.htm